# What is this line referred as in a chart?

Tags: terminology, charts

Is this called an anchor line? How is this supposed to be called?

[image: d a]

Comment: Crosshair? even if there's a single line?

Comment: That seems to be what highcharts calls it in that example, and also what I call it in my own charts.

Comment: They're anchors, unless you need a name for the two points at the same time point?

Comment: Anchors or data points, and gridlines.

Comment: @Ren: I was referring to the vertical line that moves along with the cursor. In the example shown, the cursor is at 1st Jan.

Comment: Does the line follow your mouse movements? Then you could call it a vertical cursor.

Comment: I can only see two anchors on a gridline in that image. But if there is a line between the two anchors, it could be a Reference Line to indicate that both the anchors form a pair.

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand how this is a UX question or how this name helps you, but I will explain the functionality anyway.

A crosshair is a pair of perpendicular lines (horizontal and vertical) that move when the mouse is moved or hover some important points on the graphic (depending on the requirements/ implementation). Usually, there are also two labels displayed on the X- and Y-axes in the points where the axes are crossed by the crosshair lines or a tooltip with the data.

Sometimes, a line or a label of the crosshair is hidden - the example from your image.

Maybe [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/xaxis/crosshair-both/) helps you more (it is more clear the functionality with a crosshair on both axes):

[image]

Other examples in charts:

- [google charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/crosshairs):

> Crosshairs are thin vertical and horizontal lines centered on a data point in a chart. When you, as a chart creator, enable crosshairs in your charts, your users will then be able to target a single element

[image]

- [Kendo UI for Angular](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/charts/chart/elements/crosshairs/)
  [image]
- [AnyChart](https://docs.anychart.com/Stock_Charts/Crosshair)

Comment: "_I don't understand how this is a UX question or how this name helps you_" Perhaps OP wants to refer to it in tool-tips / help-text / documentation.

Comment: @TripeHound A developer will know what to do, how to implement it or what it is. Never a designer sent me this kind of notes with names for every line (I'm also a front-end dev). This is why I added in my answer details about the functionality, that can be useful for UX. The name, not so important, nobody cares.

Comment: Without wanting to get bogged-down in a minor detail of a good answer... I never mentioned "developer". I'm talking about a term the user might see either directly in the UI or other documentation. If there _is_ an established term for a particular UI feature (and "cross-hairs" would seem to be the right one here), then using that name _can be_ important and is, I would argue, part of UX/UI (although I am predominately a developer, so not an expert on such matters).

Comment: @TripeHound I understand your point of view. I still don't think the name could help the user or the designer...

Comment: How about if someone’s patenting an idea where every single thing needs to be properly described?